# Recover xorg.conf from read only terminal

Tags: xorg, command-line

After changes in my xorg.conf, i can not restart X anymore. So on Grub i choose , limited vodeo mode, then "root prompt". Though it seems to be a read only access, so i can not replace my current xorg.conf by my saved one.

I tried to use chmod, but without success, i get a message :
"Changing permissions for xorg.conf : Read access Only" even though i entered "chmod 666 xorg.conf"

How can i modify or delete my current xorg.conf in such a scenario ?

THanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to start ubuntu normaly. When the ubuntu loading screen appears press `Escape`. You should see command line output now. It will stops at some point where LightGDM should start.

Then Press `Control+Alt+F1` to access console. You should be asked for login.

After login use

`sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` to remove the file

Or use any other command with "sudo" prepended. You will be acked for password again.

I hope it will help

Comment: When you are finished using the console, press Ctrl+Alt+F7 to return back from the console.

Comment: And when they say it's impossible to delete because it doesn't exist?

Comment: You can check if its realy there (ls command). If its missing, it is probably not the problem from original question (changed xorg.conf file)

But you can describe your problem, I will try to help.

Answer (score 2):

At boot you can press down `e` and edit the linux line to `rw` instead of `ro` and you can edit your system.  ro=read only rw=read and write and dont forget `sudo` before the `rm/etc/X11/xorg.conf` 
Good luck

Comment: Replacing `ro` with `rw` plus adding `init=/bin/sh` to boot into terminal was the solution for me. There I could remove the broken `xorg.conf`.